How to groupBy and make a filter in one of the attributes
I want to use the groupBy funtionality of prisma to take the rows and always get that one with the higher date. For example I have this in the table:



name
lastname
birthDate




'jhon'
'doe
'11-11-1911'


'jhon'
'doe
'11-11-1951'



I want as result:
{
  name: jhon
  lastname: doe
  birthDate: 11-11-1951
}

Is that possible?
